# Directly open colorbox when entering through external link

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Dear stackoverflowers,

I have a website in which you can open a page (with id) in an colorbox with iframe = true.
in this iframe (colorbox is opened) you can hit a facebook like button. In the meta data of the facebook like button, you can set a url which will be opened when clicking the article from your facebook.

What I want is the following: When someone clicks on the article on facebook, you will be lead back to the url set in the meta data of the FB like button. Right now, it opens the url, but not in a colorbox. I want this url to automatically open a colorbox.

So is it possible to directly open a colorbox when entering it from a external link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  You'll need to add some sort of information to the URL so that you can tell if it's supposed to be opened in colorbox or not (a querystring or fragment).  Then you would add a bit of script to your page to parse that url to check to see if it was supposed to be opened in colorbox.  If so you would use colorbox's open property and href property to open the correct link automatically.

It's covered briefly in the [FAQ](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq#faq-querystring)

Comment: did it by using the following solution:

    <? if($_GET['show'] == 'true' && $_GET['id']) { ?>
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
          $.colorbox({href:"popup.php?id=<?=$_GET['id']?>"});
        }); 
    </script>
     <? } ?> 'code'